# NodeJS middleware how to read from a writable stream (http.ServerResponse)

Tags: node.js, caching, middleware

I'm working on a app (using Connect **not Express**) composed of a set of middlewares plus node-http-proxy module, that is, I have a chain of middlewares like:

```
midA -> midB -> http-proxy -> midC
```

In this scenario, the response is wrote by the http-proxy that proxies the request to some target and returns the content.

I would like to create a middleware (say `midB`) to act as a cache. The idea is:

- If url is cached the cache-middleware writes the response and avoids continuing the middleares chain.
- If url is not cached the cache-middleware passes the request within the middlewares chain bit requires to read the final response content to be cached.

How can achieve this? Or there is another approach?

Cheers

Comment: So you don't want client-side caching, but save your db calls (or whatever)? I would say you can just save the response quite before sending it in some sort of hashmap and look it up in your "caching" middleware.

Comment: I just updated the question for a better explanation. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can simply use https://github.com/jpodwys/superagent-cache to make the internal HTTP call – it got everything built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. 
If you have a middleware like `function(req, res, next){..}` and need to read the content of the response object.

In this case the `res` is a `http.ServerResponse` object, a writable stream where every middleware in the chain is allowed to write content that will conform the response we want to return.

> Do not confuse with the response you get when make a request with `http.request()`, that is a `http.IncomingMessage` which in fact is a readable stream.

The way I found to read the content all middlewares write to the response is redefining the `write` method:

```
var middleare = function(req, res, next) {

  var data = "";
  res._oldWrite = res.write;
  res.write = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    data += chunck;
    return res._oldWrite.call(res, chunck, encoding, cb);
  }

  ...
}
```

Any other solutions will be appreciated.