# NodeJS respond to http.ServerResponse via stream

Tags: node.js

I'm currently experimenting with NodeJS streams and had a deeper look into the [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object that's being created upon every http request of the http.createServer request handler.

What I'm now trying to do is having the exact same API of the [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object in a different process connected via another arbitrary method (for instance using [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream)) and pipe all output of this object (including headers!) to the actual request, like the following:

```
-[http]-> server1 -[stream]-> server2 -[stream]-> server1 -[http]->
```

I've tried a couple of variants, like the following (only local) example:

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var through = require('through');
var StreamWrap = require('_stream_wrap').StreamWrap;

http.createServer(function(req, _res) {

    var resStream = through();
    resStream.pipe(_res.socket);

    resStream.__proto__.cork = function() {};
    resStream.__proto__.uncork = function() {};

    var resSocket = new StreamWrap(resStream);
    var res = new http.ServerResponse(req);
    res.assignSocket(resSocket);

    res.writeHead(201, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('hello');
    res.end();

}).listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening");
});
```

which should essentially send the raw HTTP message to the underlying socket (or not?), but for some reason I'm getting a `Segmentation fault: 11` - I'm also not sure whether I'm using the [StreamWrap](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_wrap.js) object correctly. But I think that this is not an optimal solution as the ServerResponse object handles a lot of things with regards to the socket internally.

So what would be the best way to tackle this?

If I'm piping directly to the response object, this results only in writing to the HTTP body (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851894/nodejs-middleware-how-to-read-from-a-writable-stream-http-serverresponse)), and I'm loosing the header information. So would it be best to separate header and body and then transfer them separately? How do I know when the headers are being set final on the ServerResponse object, and when the data starts (apart from other options such as trailing headers)?

Another option would be to remotely call methods on the ServerResponse Object i.e. via [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode), but isn't there a better way to do this? I would really love to be able to use Express for instance on the remotely connected server, that's why I want to keep the http.ServerResponse API.

I'm glad for any input!

Thanks!

Comment: This seemed a bit XY-ish at first. Perhaps you should put your real (high-level) goal at the beginning of your question (instead of at the end).